# Cannot create UIScrollerView with pure auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I stripped down my code so that its easy to understand.

Say you have a controller and you want to add a simple scroller using pure auto layout.

You can invoke my function tool (provided below) as follows:

```
// Create scroll view
let strip = addStripCategoryTo(view)

// Attach it to the view, vertically and horizontally
strip.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
strip.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true


// The function
func addStripCategoryTo(parent: UIView) -> UIView {

    let h:CGFloat = 128
    let w = 2*h/3
    let n = 5
    let width  = w * CGFloat(n)
    let height = h

    // Scroll view
    let scrollview = UIScrollView()
    parent.addSubview(scrollview)

    scrollview.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollview.widthAnchor .constraintEqualToAnchor(parent.widthAnchor).active = true
    scrollview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(h).active = true

    scrollview.layer.borderWidth = 2
    scrollview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    scrollview.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    // Scroll view content
    let contentView = UIView() //frame:CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size:CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
    scrollview.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.layer.borderWidth = 10
    contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.centerYAnchor).active = true
    contentView.widthAnchor .constraintEqualToConstant(width).active = true
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(height).active = true

    return scrollview
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot scroll it horizontally, see screenshot as follows:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of my issue. I provided a tool function that solve the issue as follow:

```
func setScrollViewConstraints(scrollView: UIScrollView, contentView:UIView, multiplier m:(width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat)=(1, 1)) {

    guard let scrollViewParent = scrollView.superview else {
        assert(false, "setScrollViewConstraints() requires the scrollview to have a superview")
        return
    }

    guard let contentViewParent = contentView.superview else {
        assert(false, "setScrollViewConstraints() requires the contentView to have a superview")
        return
    }

    guard contentViewParent == scrollView else {
        assert(false, "setScrollViewConstraints() requires the contentView to have a superview being the scrollView")
        return
    }

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.widthAnchor  .constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollViewParent.widthAnchor,  multiplier: m.width ).active = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor .constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollViewParent.heightAnchor, multiplier: m.height).active = true


    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.leftAnchor  .constraintEqualToAnchor(contentViewParent.leftAnchor      ).active = true
    contentView.rightAnchor .constraintEqualToAnchor(contentViewParent.rightAnchor     ).active = true
    contentView.topAnchor   .constraintEqualToAnchor(contentViewParent.topAnchor       ).active = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentViewParent.bottomAnchor    ).active = true

   /*

 // Pre-iOS 9 version

 let views = [
 "scrollView":scrollview,
 "contentView":contentView
 ]

 parent.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options:[], metrics: [:], views:views))
 parent.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options:[], metrics: [:], views:views))

 scrollview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|", options:[], metrics: [:], views:views))
 scrollview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|", options:[], metrics: [:], views:views))
 */

}
```

Use it like this for having the scroll view 100% width the super view and 1/4th of its height:

```
func addStripCategoryTo(parent: UIView) -> UIView {

    // Scroll view
    let scrollview = UIScrollView()
    parent.addSubview(scrollview)

    scrollview.backgroundColor    = UIColor.brownColor()
    scrollview.layer.borderWidth  = 2
    scrollview.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

    // Scroll view content
    let contentView = UIImageView()
    contentView.image = UIImage(named: "cover-0.jpeg")
    scrollview.addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.backgroundColor   = UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.layer.borderWidth = 10
    contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

    // Apply constraints
    setScrollViewConstraints(scrollview, contentView:contentView, multiplier: (1, 0.25))

    return scrollview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be like this,

Scrollview - top,bottom,leading,trailing

ContentView - top,bottom,leading,trailing, fixed width, vertically center in container (center y)

and your content view's width should be large than screen width then also you can scroll horizontally
Hope this will help :)

Comment: It doesn't help alas (I added one missing line form my code and a screenshot).

Comment: try to enable user interaction add this line, `scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = true` I am not sure but try if it can solve

Comment: Same thing, no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Going to give this a try and answer this, see if it helps.

**EDIT
Answering question better, old answer deleted**:

Adding these two lines should make to scroll horizontally:
`contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.leadingAnchor).active = true  contentView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.trailingAnchor).active = true`

The problem is that without these two constraint, the scrollView doesn't know its contentSize, therefor not scrolling, even though you gave the contentView a specific width. You need to let know the scrollView where does that contentView start and end, and these two constraints will help the scrollView know how big is the contentsView width. If not the scrollView's contentSize is going to stay the same as the device's width, and the contentView is just going to show offscreen since it's width is larger than the device's screen.

Hope this helped better.

Full code of the function

```
    func addStripCategoryTo(parent: UIView)-> UIView {

    let h:CGFloat = 128
    let w = 2*h/3
    let n = 5
    let width  = w * CGFloat(n)
    let height = h

    // Scroll view
    let scrollview = UIScrollView()
    parent.addSubview(scrollview)

    scrollview.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(parent.leadingAnchor).active = true
    scrollview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(parent.trailingAnchor).active = true
    scrollview.widthAnchor .constraintEqualToAnchor(parent.widthAnchor).active = true
    scrollview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(h).active = true

    scrollview.layer.borderWidth = 2
    scrollview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    scrollview.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    // Scroll view content
    let contentView = UIView() //frame:CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size:CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
    scrollview.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.layer.borderWidth = 10
    contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.centerYAnchor).active = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.leadingAnchor).active = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.trailingAnchor).active = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(width).active = true
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(height).active = true

    return scrollview
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: How to scroll horizontally, and I gave some tips on how to build the scrollView with Auto Layout and for it to be scrolling horizontally. What did I miss?

Comment: Yup, just copy/paste my code in an simple view controller to try by yourself.

Comment: I think you need to add leading and trailing constraint to the contentView with the scrollview.

`contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.leadingAnchor).active = true`
        `contentView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollview.trailingAnchor).active = true`

this helps the scrollView know its contentSize (in this case the contentView's width).